# Pop OS 20.04: How do I switch graphics drivers (Nouveau to propietary) without messing up the display?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nouveau

**Moved this question over from AskUbuntu.**

I've looked everywhere online for a solution. I've tried multiple times to install the appropriate Nvidia drivers for my graphics card (**which is a GTX 680**). I've also tried blacklisting Nouveau, to no avail. I'm desperate for a solution, especially considering how a lot of games don't work properly with Nouveau.

The only results that I got from attempting to install the appropriate Nvidia drivers were... bad, at best. Upon reboot, systemd would apparently works as intended. But, upon reaching a certain part in the init (around "Reaching target Bluetooth/Swap"), the upper part of the display is corrupted like crazy and the part below remains frozen. (see image below)

[image]

Side note: this happens even when booting into multi-user mode. Also, **the card is flashed to work with macOS Mojave**, so I suspect that might be the reason why.

All help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start by apologizing if this is way off base, or if this isn't applicable at all, but every time I've run into some graphical issue and it's occurring during boot, I look towards nomodeset.

Check out this answer here:

[nomodeset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do)

For information on what nomodeset actually does.

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work. Same graphical error.